# In Java, how would I print a 2d array that resembles a seating chart?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have an assignment where I would have to print a 2d array (8 rows and 7 columns) that resembles a seating chart with an aisle going down the middle that cannot have any seats (these elements would be left blank). The chart would have to have a number for each seat, and continue in ascending order (as seen below).

```
1  2  3 x  4  5  6
7  8  9 x 10 11 12
13 14 15 x 16 17 18
19 20 21 x 22 23 24
```

The program would continue until there would be 48 total seats.
I have to print the array with for loops (which I have no problem doing), but I do not know how to make a blank column (the column with xs), or how to make each number increase as you progress through the cells.

Right now, I have only the for loops that would print out the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need there is a nested loop. Your code should look like this:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    print_2d_array(8, 7);
 }


 public static void print_2d_array(int rows, int columns) {
    int x = rows/2;
    int y = columns - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // number of rows
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) { // number of columns
            System.out.print((j + y*i + 1) + " "); // That's the formula I was talking about
            if(j == (y/2)-1) System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Comment: For my code, ```j``` would have to equal 3, correct?

Comment: No because we're printing it just after the `if`.

Hint for the formula: ? + column*? + 1

Comment: Are you referring to using a ternary operator?

Comment: Oh wait, I guess I didn't get what you wanted first. I just changed the code. I hope it helps.

Comment: Works good, but some issues. On the right hand side of the aisle, there is an extra column. This extra column on the right hand side makes it one row too short. I tried tinkering with the code, but I cannot seem to fix it.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. You're talking about the spacing between values?